# Is it possible to stop prettier from adding an extra tab for .then() {} statements after Promise.try?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, code-formatting, prettier

So, I was wondering if it is possible to stop prettier from adding an extra tab for `.then() {}` statements after `Promise.try` or just simple `return PromiseFn() .then(() => {})..`

Usually, I write promise chains, that look something like this:

```
import Promise from "Bluebird"

Promise.try() {
  // code..
})
.then(() => {
  // more core
})
.then(() => {
 // more code
})
```

How prettier makes it look like:

```
Promise.try() {
  // code..
})
  .then(() => {
    // more core
  })
  .then(() => {
   // more code
  })
```

So I was wondering, if it is possible to stop prettier from adding the extra, non-needed tab before all the `.then()` statements?

Comment: What is `Promise.try`? Your code is syntactically invalid...

Comment: Added an import explaining it. Though, as I have mentioned, doesn't matter what you use, all .then(()=>...) even after return, always get formatted 1 non-needed tab away

Comment: Ok, but `Promise.try(){` should be `Promise.try(()=>{`, right? The former is erroneous.

Answer (score 2):

It seems Prettier is a ***very*** [opinionated](https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html) formatter...

But you may be able to flag to Prettier to [ignore](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html) the next node

```
// prettier-ignore
Promise.try() {
  // code..
})
.then(() => {
  // more core
})
.then(() => {
 // more code
})
```

We dropped using Prettier in our project for this reason, it didn't allow for formatting how we wanted to. And TBH I'm not even sure the above will still work for what you want, but it seems the best option to try.

Comment: What did you replace Prettier with in your project?

Comment: @CSquared I misspoke a bit. We didn't drop Prettier entirely, we still use it for a few IDE specific styling things that esLint doesn't cover, but effectively we use esLint rules and VSCode's settings to auto-format/auto-fix on save.